# Python Try statements not activating correctly

Tags: python-3.x, syntax, try-except

I am trying to get a try statement to activate, but it's not working properly:

```
import datetime
import re
import sys

debug = True
log = sys.stdout

dates = ['1/1/2010', '1-Jan-2010']
def date_fixer(date):
    constant = datetime.date(1899, 12, 30)
    if debug : print("Fix this date: ", date, file=log)
    if date.strip() == "None" : return ""
    if len(date) == 4 : return date
    try:
        if date == datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%Y').strftime('%m/%d/%Y'):
            print("Hello.")
    except:
        try:
            if date == datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%d-%b-%Y').strftime('%d-%b-%Y'):
                print("Bye.")
        except:
            print("Something went wrong.")
    else:
        print("Your program is working fine.")

for date in dates:
    date_fixer(date)
```

The The first date (1/1/2010) returns most of what I want to see on screen:

```
Fix this date: 1/1/2010
Your program is working fine.
```

The second date (1-Jan-2010) only shows:

```
Fix this date: 1-Jan-2010
```

I've looked and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong; I'm wondering if it has something to do with it being in a function? I got this try/except to work, looking online:

```
str = input("Enter a number: ")
try:
    num = int(str)
    if num > 100:
        print("More than 100.")
    elif num == 100:
        print("Is 100")
    else:
        print("Less than 100.")
except:
    print("Enter a number, only.")
else:
    print("Program working fine.")
```

Can someone please help me understand why my try statements aren't catching the print statements?

Comment: The result of your inner `.strftime()` call is `01-Jan-2010`, which indeed does not equal the original `date`.  There does not appear to be a strftime format code that avoids that leading zero.

Comment: From the python docs: **The try … except statement has an optional else clause, which, when present, must follow all except clauses. It is useful for code that must be executed if the try clause does not raise an exception**.

And your code has one execution path where in the outer try block an exception is raised(so the corresponding else block won't be executed), and then in the inner try block the if condition evaluates to false(no exception is raised in here) and therefore no print statements get executed

Comment: @jasonharper Thank you very much for calling out the leading zero (zero padding), as I didn't realize this was an issue before. I've been using the last hour to search around and try different scenarios to get dates to parse correctly when there is no leading zero and am coming up blank. Essentially what I'm trying to create is a tool that will take various forms of date input and spit it back out in an 'acceptable' format of just %Y%m%d.
As far as the try/except, I think I got that working, but it's again a matter of matching the date format to what I'm checking. Thanks @tkhurana96!